# "Lista" continua nula depois de usar append Python

Tags: python

Gostaria de entender o motivo de t2 ser nulo após atribuição de t1+append.

```
t1=[1,2]
t2=t1.append(3)
print(t2)
```

Comment: .append age na lista, e retorn none, o correto ai, seria apenas, t1.append(3); print(t1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O método append() não tem retorno, ele faz simplesmente a ação de adicionar um novo item a lista. Portanto, quando você tenta "printar" um retorno de append, ele retorna none.

Você pode fazer assim para dar certo:

```
t1=[1,2]
t2=t1
t2.append(3)
print(t2)
```

Answer (score 1):

Oi, o append é grudar um novo elemento (pode ser uma nova lista) em uma lista atual.
Para adicionar 3 no final da lista o comando é:

```
t1=[1,2]
t1.append(3)
print(t1)
```

Agora se você quiser fazer append de uma lista na outra primeiro você precisa declarar a outra, aí ficaria

```
t1=[1,2]
t2=[3,4]
t1.append(t2)
print(t1)
```